# Dividing page in two parts

Tags: html

I want to divide page horizontally in two parts. On upper part I want a form and on lower part I want an image. But it's not working. Please help me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>JN DIAMONDS</title>
    </head>
        <style>    
            #upper {
                height:50%;
            }

            #lower {
                height: 50%;
                background-image: r1.jpg;
            }
        </style>
    <body>
        <div id="upper">

            <form align="center" method="POST" action="insert_rough.php">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>JN Patel <b>Rough Diamond</b> Information</legend>
                    <br>
                    <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="Name" required><br><br>
                    <input type="text" name="twait" placeholder="Total Rough Weight"><br><br>
                    <input type="text" name="cprice" placeholder="1 Carat Price"><br><br>
                    <input type="text" name="dprice" placeholder="Dollar Rate"><br><br>
                    <input type="text" name="date" placeholder="Payment Days" required><br><br>
                    <input type="image" src="submit.jpg" alt="Submit" width="90" height="35"><br>
                </fieldset>
        </div>
        <body>
            <div id="lower"></div>
        </body>
            </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have edited your post to make it readable by humans (that's what you will mostly find here). I'm pretty sure that nesting a `body` tag into another is a bad idea.

Comment: i m not getting backgrund img..will u pls help

Comment: are these two body tags? why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I took out the extra body tag and added an image under the form. Here is a working codepen of what I think you want.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/epeWYQ?editors=100

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>JN DIAMONDS</title>
    </head>
        <style>    
            #upper {
                height:50%;
            }

            #lower {
                height: 50%;
                background-image: r1.jpg;
            }
        </style>
    <body>
        <div id="upper">

            <form align="center" method="POST" action="insert_rough.php">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>JN Patel <b>Rough Diamond</b> Information</legend>
                    <br>
                    <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="Name" required><br><br>
                    <input type="text" name="twait" placeholder="Total Rough Weight"><br><br>
                    <input type="text" name="cprice" placeholder="1 Carat Price"><br><br>
                    <input type="text" name="dprice" placeholder="Dollar Rate"><br><br>
                    <input type="text" name="date" placeholder="Payment Days" required><br><br>
                    <input type="image" src="submit.jpg" alt="Submit" width="90" height="35"><br>
                </fieldset>
        </div>

            <div id="lower"></div>
          <img src="http://i.cdn.turner.com/asfix/repository//8a250ba13f865824013fc9db8b6b0400/thumbnail_8234390180613999969.jpg" alt="" />

            </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

You need an image tag which is why it’s not working if you're linking it to css use background: url(./img/r1.jpg) no-repeat; you need to change the img folder name to whatever the folder is called that you keep your images in.